# Identifying where a package came from

Tags: macos, command-line, administrator, utilities, package-management

I just tried to upgrade `nmap` with my package manager but got knocked back because it's supposedly not installed. Even though it is:

```
brew upgrade nmap  
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.
Error: nmap not installed
```

```
nmap --version 
Nmap version 6.40-2 ( http://nmap.org )
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
Compiled with: liblua-5.2.2 openssl-0.9.7l nmap-libpcre-7.6 nmap-libpcap-1.2.1 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: kqueue poll select
```

```
brew info nmap
nmap: stable 7.60 (bottled), HEAD
Port scanning utility for large networks
https://nmap.org/
Conflicts with:
  ndiff (because both install ndiff binaries)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/nmap.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔
Optional: pygtk ✘
==> Options
--with-pygtk
    Build Zenmap GUI
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Is it possible to find how a package, utility, or application came to be present, and/or installed on a macOS host? I recall being able to do something like this in the past, on a Linux (Debian) host, and figured there might be some kind of system or utility in place for macOS.

Answer (score 1):

This will show you your installed brew packages

```
brew list
```

There may be options in other package managers, but nmap can also be installed by downloading the disk image and installing manually.

Comment: That's not really the question..

Comment: @tjt263 Oh, of course. I don’t think there is a general way to show how any software was installed, I suspect you will have to exhaust the possibilities one at a time.